# nuget package with legacy DLLs

Tags: nuget

I want to create a nuget package that contains besides .NET assemblies "legacy" DLLs (non .NET DLLs), which are referenced or accessed by the assembly DLLs. 
Where do I put these DLLs? How does the users program (exe), which uses my package, get access to these DLLs?

I can only think of two ways the users program can access these DLLs: either there is a PATH environment variable set to the appropriate directory or these DLLs are copied into the *bin/Release* and *bin/Debug* directories of the users project.

How would I deal with x86 and x64 versions of the legacy DLLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at adding a custom MSBuild .targets to your NuGet package. Inside this .targets file you can define any MSBuild tasks you need which will allow you to hook into the build of the project. So you could have the non-.NET dlls copied into the output directory using MSBuild.

The PostSharp NuGet package is one example that copies extra files around during the build. However its MSBuild .targets file is fairly complex. You would not need to do anything as complicated as that. Probably something simple similar to:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PrepareForRunDependsOn>$(PrepareForRunDependsOn);MyPostBuildTarget</PrepareForRunDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <ExtraFile Include="dlls\*.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="MyPostBuildTarget">
   <Copy SourceFiles="@(ExtraFile)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

The above is only an idea of what you could do.