# Including a non referenced dll from a package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, project-reference, nuspec

I have a nuspec file that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyDll.Service</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>MyDll.Service</title>
    <authors>MyDll</authors>
    <owners>MyDll</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Description</description>
    <copyright>Copyright © 2017</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="SomeDll" version="1.0.0" />
    </dependencies>
    <references>
      <reference file="MyDll.Service.Context.dll" />
    </references>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..\..\Folder\MyDll.Service.Context\bin\Release\MyDll.Service.Context.dll" target="lib\net452"/>
    <file src="..\..\Folder\MyDll.Service\bin\Release\MyDll.Service.dll" target="lib\net452"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

This generates me a nuget package that contains 2 dlls.  The project itself only references `MyDll.Service.Context.dll` (which is exactly what I want).

I am using injection to insert the `MyDll.Service.dll` wherever the classes for `MyDll.Service.Context.dll` are mentioned. My only problem is that when I build, the dll `MyDll.Service.dll` is not pulled into the bin folder of the main project. Only the `MyDll.Service.Context.dll` is. This makes sense because I only reference the context dll.

My question, how can I get `MyDll.Service.dll` pulled into the bin folder upon building and publishing the project, without having to reference that dll in the project?

EDIT:

As per suggestion in the comments I tried to do this with MSBuild. I changed my nuspec to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyDll.Service</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>MyDll.Service</title>
    <authors>MyDll</authors>
    <owners>MyDll</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Description</description>
    <copyright>Copyright © 2017</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="SomeDll" version="1.0.0" />
    </dependencies>
    <references>
      <reference file="MyDll.Service.Context.dll" />
    </references>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..\..\Folder\MyDll.Service.Context\bin\Release\MyDll.Service.Context.dll" target="lib\net452"/>
    <file src="..\..\Folder\MyDll.Service\bin\Release\MyDll.Service.dll" target="lib\net452"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

Unfortunately, all that did was cause my `MyDll.Service.dll` dll to show up twice in my package, once in the build folder and once in the lib folder. However, upon build the dll was still not in the folder.

Comment: I would probably look at using an MSBuild target that you ship with your NuGet package similar to what is described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016850/nuget-package-with-legacy-dlls/33018794#33018794

Comment: @MattWard what is .targets? Is that a property inside nuspec file or is it a file on its own? What is this practice called, as in what can I search to find online a guide on how to get this done? I looked at that SO answer but its very vague.

Comment: It is an MSBuild file which you can include in your NuGet package - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#including-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package

Comment: @MattWard Thank you for that. I have to be honest and admit I am still quite a bit lost as to how this works. Tried googling for more but came up short. Do you happen to have an example somewhere I can look up? What I am mostly confused about is that the article mentions props and targets and it doesn't mention anywhere how I link my dll's that I want.

Comment: There is an example in the original stackoverflow post. It will copy a file to the output directory when building. If you need to do something else I would just get it working in your project first and then see how/what is created for that file and then basically copy it to the .targets file that will be part of your NuGet package.